# Where can I find some maps showing where the stations and lines of micros and other types of mini-buses (e.g., combis) are located in Lima, Peru?

Tags: transportation, maps, peru, lima

According to the [Wikipedia page on Transport in Lima](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Transport_in_Lima&oldid=921808448):

> Micros (minibus) are the most common means of public transportation in Lima.

I could find some maps for the stations/lines of the [Metropolitano (bus rapid transit opened in 2010)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolitano_%28Lima%29) and the [metro (opened in 2011)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lima_Metro)  in  Lima, but was unable to easily find similar maps for minibuses.

Where can I find some maps showing where the stations and lines of micros and other types of mini-buses (e.g., combis) are located in Lima?